# Want to use same Adapter with different Activities and different row_layouts

Tags: java, android

I want my Adapter to choose either one row_layout or another row_layout, depending on which Activity is sending the data. There are two Activities sending data.

At the moment I only know how to make the Adapter use one row_layout. I can't work out how to write the extra code to make it choose a different row_layout, depending on which Activity is sending the data. (There wont be any checkbox in the second row_layout).

Here is my Adapter:

```java
public class ShopItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShopItem> {

public ShopItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ShopItem> shopItem){
    super(context, 0, shopItem);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
    }

    TextView tvItem = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemName);
    TextView tvQty = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvQuantity);
    CheckBox cbIsPurchased = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbIsPurchased);

    ShopItem _shopItem = getItem(position);

    tvItem.setText(_shopItem.getItemName());
    tvQty.setText(String.valueOf(_shopItem.getQuantity()));

    if(_shopItem.getIsPurchased() == 1){
        cbIsPurchased.setChecked(true);
    }
    else{
        cbIsPurchased.setChecked(false);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: you have fixed number of activity which uses this Adapter?

Comment: Yes, I have TWO Activities which use this Adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some parameter to the ShopItemAdapter constructor to distinguish from which Activity is called, but if that implies to use many if conditionals in getView code then i think it's better to write several adapters, you will have a much clear code.

Comment: What parameters should I add to the constructor? 

I think I know how to write the conditionals for getView. I just don't have a clue what parameters to put in the constructor.

Comment: public class ShopItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShopItem> {

    private boolean mIsActivity1;

    /// Constructor ///
    public ShopItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ShopItem> shopItem, boolean isActivity1) {
        super(context, 0, shopItem);
        mIsActivity1 = isActivity1;
    }
    
    // then in getView you can use mIsActivity1 to distinguish activities ..........

Comment: ok, thanx for that. How does mIsActivity1 know about my two Activities? I'm having trouble understanding exactly what inside the adapter refers to the Activities.  Is it getContext()?  Is it parent? Is it convertView? I'm really not very smart at this at all.